# Builder and Factory method in one

Tags: c#, .net, builder

I find that injecting builder into classes I can never be sure as to the state in which the builder is in. I am thinking of providing the builder with the ability to build... itself.

Has anyone ever done something like this?

```
public interface IProductBuilder{
   // Creates a new instance of the builder
   IProductBuilder Create();

   // Adds a part
   IProductBuilder Add(IPart Part);

   // Creates the product
   IProduct Build();
}
```

Here is a use case:

```
[Export]
public class SomeClass : ISomeService{
    [ImportingConstructor] // inject through MEF
    public SomeClass(IProductBuilder builder){
        this.builder = builder;
    }
   public IBar bar SomeFunction(IPart foo)
   {
     var mybuilder = builder.Create(); // was the builder populated?
     builder.Add(foo); 
     return builder.build();
   }
}
```

Of course, this would mean that the builder itself will either be created in-vain all the time or I can make it singleton.

Any feedback, appreciated.

Comment: Why is your builder stateful? And what are you doing with mybuilder?

Comment: Agree with Daniel, why is an existing instance of a builder responsible for factory behavior?  (let alone mutation with `.Add`)

Comment: Um.. all builders are stateful.

Comment: @drozzy, yes, internally.  It's just strange (to me) that it's stateful as part of its public interface.

Comment: And why is an instance method being passed an object that is (presumably) being added to some collection of the class relying on a builder? Why not just add to the collection directly?

Comment: @drozzy ok, technically yes. Let's look at this another way - how many times do you new up a StringBuilder, build up your string, call ToString() then re-use the same StringBuilder? The problem is really 'injecting a builder into classes'. Why would you inject a builder of a certain class into the class itself? I think I'm really just not understanding what the actual problem is here! You could of course new up a builder in a factory method but I wouldn't reuse the same builder over and over once it's built it's product

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I think I got confused between injecting services and actual domain objects. In a sense, builder is a domain object... and it is the builder that is responsible for injecting dependencies into other things... Anyways I gota sleep on this stuff! Thanks guys

Comment: @drozzy FWIW I've just come across a _similar_ case at work. One of the guys put a static `Create` method on a Builder class so, to answer your question, 'Has anyone ever done something like this?' the answer is yes! If it works, solves the problem, is maintainable, and doesn't introduce unnecessary abstraction then there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Daniel Lol, static method wouldn't cut it for DI, since statics are not visible through interfaces. :-) Made me smile, thanks.

Comment: @drozzy well I did say 'similar' rather than same! I thought it was funny that just after commenting I found that method in our codebase...